# Display edit link for a node in a view when user has permission

Tags: views, 6

I have a view displaying fields from one node.

Is it possible to display a link for a user to edit the node if they are logged in and have the appropriate permission to edit?  Something similar to the tabs with edit displayed for a regular themed node would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Views, there is a field you can add called `Node: Edit link` that will display a link to the edit page for the node, taking into account the user's permissions.

[image: Node edit link]

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty obvious.  I'm surprised I've never seen that before.

Comment: Do you know what permission settings need to be enabled in order for that link to show up in a custom role?